# Картинки из номенклатуры в SQL в 1С

Tags: 1с, sql

Как 1с торговля хранит в sql картинки из номенклатуры и как их достать от туда?

Answer (score 1):

Картинки в 1С хранятся в специальном контейнере "ХранилищеЗначений". 
Этот Контейнер сериализует их в некий внутренний формат. И затем уже происходит запись в SQL. Тип поля в SQL, при этом имеет тип image.

Вот некий пример получения картинки из поля SQL. Правда пример написан на С#. Но разобраться можно.
[Получение картинки из ХранилищеЗначений](http://igorus1977.ya.ru/replies.xml?item_no=1462)